# How to output results to CSV of a concurrent web scraper in Go?

Tags: csv, go, concurrency, web-scraping, goquery

I'm new to Go and am trying to take advantage of the concurrency in Go to build a basic scraper to pull extract title, meta description, and meta keywords from URLs.

I am able to print out the results to terminal with the concurrency but can't figure out how to write output to CSV. I've tried many a variations that I could think of with limited knowledge of Go and many end up breaking the concurrency - so losing my mind a bit.

My code and URL input file is below - Thanks in advance for any tips!

```
// file name: metascraper.go
package main

import (
    // import standard libraries
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
    // import third party libraries
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func csvParsing() {
    file, err := os.Open("data/sample.csv")
    checkError("Cannot open file ", err)

    if err != nil {
        // err is printable
        // elements passed are separated by space automatically
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    // automatically call Close() at the end of current method
    defer file.Close()
    //
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    // options are available at:
    // http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/csv/reader.go?s=3213:3671#L94
    reader.Comma = ';'
    lineCount := 0

    fileWrite, err := os.Create("data/result.csv")
    checkError("Cannot create file", err)
    defer fileWrite.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(fileWrite)
    defer writer.Flush()

    for {
        // read just one record
        record, err := reader.Read()
        // end-of-file is fitted into err
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            return
        }

        go func(url string) {
            // fmt.Println(msg)
            doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(url)
            if err != nil {
                checkError("No URL", err)
            }

            metaDescription := make(chan string, 1)
            pageTitle := make(chan string, 1)

            go func() {
                // time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
                // use CSS selector found with the browser inspector
                // for each, use index and item
                pageTitle <- doc.Find("title").Contents().Text()

                doc.Find("meta").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
                    if item.AttrOr("name", "") == "description" {
                        metaDescription <- item.AttrOr("content", "")
                    }
                })
            }()
            select {
            case res := <-metaDescription:
                resTitle := <-pageTitle
                fmt.Println(res)
                fmt.Println(resTitle)

                // Have been trying to output to CSV here but it's not working

                // writer.Write([]string{url, resTitle, res})
                // err := writer.WriteString(`res`)
                // checkError("Cannot write to file", err)

            case <-time.After(time.Second * 2):
                fmt.Println("timeout 2")
            }

        }(record[0])

        fmt.Println()

        lineCount++
    }
}

func main() {

    csvParsing()

    //Code is to make sure there is a pause before program finishes so we can see output
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}

func checkError(message string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(message, err)
    }
}
```

The data/sample.csv input file with URLs:

```
    http://jonathanmh.com
    http://keshavmalani.com
    http://google.com
    http://bing.com
    http://facebook.com
```

Comment: You had the right idea, you were just simply closing the `fileWriter` before you have a chance to write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you supplied, you had commented the following code:

```
// Have been trying to output to CSV here but it's not working
err = writer.Write([]string{url, resTitle, res})
checkError("Cannot write to file", err)
```

This code is correct, except you have one issue.
Earlier in the function, you have the following code:

```
fileWrite, err := os.Create("data/result.csv")
checkError("Cannot create file", err)
defer fileWrite.Close()
```

This code causes the fileWriter to close once your `csvParsing()` func exits.
Because you've closed fileWriter with the defer, you are unable to write to it in your concurrent function.

**Solution:**
You'll need to use `defer fileWrite.Close()` **inside your concurrent func** or something similar so you do not close the fileWriter before you have written to it.

Comment: I tried the following
`fmt.Println(resTitle)
err := writer.Write([]string{"url", "resTitle", "res"})
err2 := writer.Write([]string{url, resTitle, res})
checkError("Cannot write to file", err)
checkError("Cannot write to file", err2)`

and moved `defer fileWrite.Close()` after `lineCount++}` but I just get blank csv file

Here is go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/eL1Bn8Xsv6

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/1QwszPd7f7

This updated link should avoid the error saying "File already closed". I did this by removing `defer writer.Close()`.

If you want an example with `defer writer.Close()`, then you can use wait groups to wait for the concurrent functions to finish executing before the file is closed.

Here is an example: https://play.golang.org/p/RzLYEIW6CP